# Creating list of objects of generic type T using a constructor throws: "Construct on type System.RuntimeType not found" exception

Tags: c#, reflection

(Solved)
 Thank you all for your answers. Let me explain my problem better in my poor english.
 I have a class A which has a DataTable field. This DataTable could be different per instance of A. On the other hand I have models classes that takes a row in the constructor and bind to the row so I can treat DataTable rows like objects. What I'm trying to achieve is a method "`List<T> GenerateResultList<T>()`" that foreach row instanciate a model of type T passing the row to the constructor. There will be only one class of type T (model). This is my attempt, and now is working:

```
   public List<T> GenModelsFromResults<T>()
    {

        var db = FarmaDB.Instance;
        var modelType = db.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)));
        var result = new List<T>();

        _resultsTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
           .ForEach(row =>
           {
               result.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(modelType, row);
           }); 

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What's the object from `db`?

Comment: If you already know the type `T` that you want to exactly match (as in `== typeof(T)`), then why do you need reflection in the first place? Just use `T`.

Comment: Well there's only one class of ***exactly*** type T, right? Or did you mean all types that are assignable to type `T`?

Comment: Why does it have to be Assembly type? If you only want to create an instance of T it can be done other way.

Comment: ... in which case, [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend.